# How to create custom marker on openLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I want to create a marker with an image inside and a stroke shape like this.
I don't understand how to do this?
Maybe I need to somehow add a css class and edit it through styles?

[image]

```
 const style = new Style({
        image: new Icon({
          anchor: [0.5, 46],
          anchorXUnits: "fraction",
          anchorYUnits: "pixels",
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          src: "src/avatar.png",
        }),
      })
```

This is how I create a marker with an image. But how to make a white background and corner for it?

```
 const style = new Style({
        image: new Icon({
          anchor: [0.5, 46],
          anchorXUnits: "fraction",
          anchorYUnits: "pixels",
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          src: "src/avatar.png",
        }),
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create whatever you need in a canvas then use it as the icon

For example

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const radius = 24;
canvas.width = radius * 2;
canvas.height = canvas.width;
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.arc(radius, radius, radius, -Math.PI, Math.PI / 2);
context.lineTo(0, radius * 2);
context.closePath();
context.clip();
context.fillStyle = 'white';
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.beginPath();
context.arc(radius, radius, radius * 0.75, 0, Math.PI * 2);
context.clip();
context.fillStyle = 'blue';
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

the either

```
const iconStyle = new Style({
  image: new Icon({
    anchor: [0, 1],
    src: canvas.toDataURL(),
  }),
});
```

or

```
const iconStyle = new Style({
  image: new Icon({
    anchor: [0, 1],
    img: canvas
  }),
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/icon-forked-gh4h3j?file=/main.js